# API Response Date Format

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script making an API request to get a date. The date, however, is coming back as a number in scientific notation (1.635218706E9) which I'm assuming is in the format of milliseconds from 1970. After converting it from scientific notation to a regular number (1635218706) creating a new javascript date with it the wrong date and year. It should be Oct 25 2021, but instead gives Dec 31 1969.

Am I missing something when creating a new date from the number? And is there a way just have the API respond with a more readable date instead of milliseconds from 1970?

Comment: About `is there a way just have the API respond with a more readable date instead of milliseconds from 1970?`, can you provide the detailed information about the API you are using? And also, can you provide your script?

Comment: The value appears to be seconds, not milliseconds, so change the exponent from 9 to 12, or multiply by 1000 (1e3): `new Date(1.635218706E9 * 1e3).toISOString()` gives "2021-10-26T03:25:06.000Z". The multiplication will also coerce a string to Number so `new Date('1.635218706E9' * 1e3).toISOString()` works too. :-)

Comment: This appears to have fixed it. Didn't consider that maybe it was in seconds, not milliseconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case. I found if you multiply this number by 1000 and feed it to Data object you can get something a little bit more reasonable:

```js
var seconds = 1.635218706E9;
var date = new Date(seconds*1000);
console.log(date); // output: 2021-10-26T03:25:06.000Z

var date_str = [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate()].join('/')
console.log(date_str); // output: 2021/10/26
```

It looks like the API gives you seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you can use toLocaleString / toLocaleDateString

so the code is like this

```
const dates = new Date()
const fullDates = dates.toLocaleString('en-US')
```

you can read in documentation here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString